# Enable only year in Material-UI DatePicker with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm having trouble with trying to enable a Material-UI DatePicker to only receive year, the user won't be able to put or select month and day. I've already tried some options, but is still not working. Anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: `I've already tried some options, but is still not working` What other options did you try? :)

Comment: Hi! Try to be more specific to your issue by adding an example on code you trying to solve.

Answer (score 6):

There is a prop called `views` which is exactly for this purpose. It receives an array of types that should be rendered:

```
Array<"year" | "date" | "month">
```

So just pass `year` to it:

```
<DatePicker views={['year']} />
```

[image: Edit material-ui-pickers-usage-demo]

Comment: Great idea for shortcut to sandbox!! Do you mind to use it ? :)

Comment: Never mind, I just liked the idea you use to link to codesandbox by using this image

Comment: Yes I've figured out this, Good idea!

Comment: Not mine sadly :(

Comment: It's called `Sandbox button`. One of many ways to share a sandbox